# What's wrong with my sisyphus.js/jquery html? Losing user form input on re-opening page

Tags: javascript, forms, client-side

I'm trying to build a very simple word programming web app [Tome](http://streamerforipad.webs.com/Tome/Tome.html), with the functionality of saving the form input locally using [sisyphus.js](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/). I've called jquery in the correct order, followed all the syntax that Alexander Kaupanin provides, and it still reverts to default text on

*UPDATED*

reopening of the page (a reload works just as it should on Firefox, but not on Safari). There's about a metric tonne of html, so I won't paste the whole source here, but the `<head>` goes like this:

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
    "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
      Tome | A simple text editor
    </title>
    <link href="dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title=
    "default" />
    <link href="light.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type=
    "text/css" title="alternate" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href=
    "print.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
    "http://streamerforipad.webs.com/Tome/sisyphus.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function() { $('form').sisyphus(); }); </script>
  </head>
```

Any suggestions would be great, I'm relatively new to this whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $( &#039;#form&#039; ).sisyphus({timeout: 5});
</script>`

is not correct!

This is the correct code:

**`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('form').sisyphus(); 
    });
</script>`**

& #039; = '

Good luck! I've great problem in storage data... :(

Comment: Thanks alot! This works... sort of. It remains when you refresh the page, but not when you close and re-open :( This seems to be a tricky field of work.